# Combine WCF and WCF DataService

Tags: wcf, architecture, wcf-data-services

I'm looking to create an Application Object Server that is sitting between Window form client and SQL 2008R2 Database, it handling application business rule and support CRUD, I have achive this with WCF and WCF dataservice in the past, It would be better if we can combine those two kind of WCFs into one.
Do you know any way to achive this? or we should go back to the WinSock day.

Awaiting for your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Data Services are based on the REST-style WCF services (`webHttpBinding`) - so those are quite fundamentally different from the traditional SOAP-style WCF bindings.

I don't see how you could easily combine WCF Data Services with a traditional SOAP WCF service (assuming that's what you're trying to do).

What you could do is:

- create an entity data model as basis for both services
- create the WCF Data Service on top of that EDM
- separately create a set of WCF SOAP service methods, based on the same EDM

But SOAP and REST are quite different, at a very basic level:

- REST tends to work with **resources** - you have a `Customer` (also in your URL), and you can fetch it, edit it, update it, delete it
- SOAP on the other hand tends to work more with **operations** - you have your customer, but then you expose methods like `GetCustomer`, `UpdateCustomer` etc. - your basic building blocks are methods that take parameters

Comment: Thank you for getting back, your suggestion is exactly what I have done, I just feel that I would be nice to have one kind of technology could do resource+operations,  WCF and WCF Data service

Comment: It seems that we don't have a kind of WCF that equals to WCF + WCF DataService for net tcp and window forms.

Comment: @user1092875: no, as I said - you have two fairly distinct styles of WCF - the SOAP (the original) and the new REST (WCF Data Service is based on that). WCF as a technology supports both - but they are and feel quite a bit different

Comment: It is not only distinct in styles, it is also difference in application programming support such as you can do CRUD with dataservice but it is too hard with raw WCF, TCP with dataservice isn't possible...just name a few. Lot of people talk about WCF, It doesn't seem people uses the technology in critical business apllication. We have decided to write our application ground up, it is hard but it is worth it, we went with WCF in the past and We just fell lost because its technology doesnt seem to married with each other, we are now writting from ground up and we feel lot more confident long term